# Get windows visibility at app shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an application that has one main window the a number of child windows. I want to be able to get the visibility of the child windows and save it when the user closes the application.

The events I tried are the following

- [`Window.Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Window.Closed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Aplication.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`UIElement.IsVisibleChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

The problems is that they are called in the following order

1. `ChildWindow.VisibleChanged`
2. `ChildWindow.Closing`
3. `ChildWindow.Closed`
4. `MainWindow.Closing`
5. `MainWindow.Closed`
6. `Application.Exit`

So when the application exists or the main window closes all the child windows are invisible and there's no way for me to know if the user had them opened or not.

Is there an different event i should listen to or a different way to do it ?

**Update**

I've managed to reproduce it in a empty wpf application.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window dummyWindow = new Window();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        this.IsVisibleChanged +=(s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("Main visiblity changed");
        this.Closing +=(s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("Main closing");
        this.Closed +=(s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("Main closed");
        Application.Current.Exit +=(s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("App exit");
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        dummyWindow.Show();
        dummyWindow.Owner = this;
        dummyWindow.IsVisibleChanged += (s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("Dummy visiblity changed");
        dummyWindow.Closing += (s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("Dummy closing");
        dummyWindow.Closed += (s,ev) => Debug.WriteLine("Dummy closed");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Odd, child windows do not go invisible before you get the chance to say "no dont close the app" so.. closing should be sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this happens because when an application closes, the order in which WPF closes the windows is the one in which they're created, it doesn't close the `MainWindow` first. 
Have a look at the [`DoShutdown`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,9121ac19c6eb9747) method.

If my case the first window is the `dummyWindow` because the initializer runs before the constructor of `MainWindow` meaning that the base constructor for `dummyWindow` is called first which [adds the window to the `Application.WindowsInternal` list](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,1357fc2806388b54).

The easiest way to fix this is to make sure that the construction of any other child windows occurs after the construction of the `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of the program when it closes.

You can serialise your ViewModel and save it on disk then load it again when the program is restarted.